Individual solution for each student using datatool in schule
Completely rewritten question.
The package schule provides me with a table called "Erwartungshorizont" (image 1). In this table are three columns:

solution to each question which i write directly begind the question for the exam.
the points which can be gained for each question
blank

In this third column I want to print the points each student has reached for each question. This would look like in image 2. Here I have made it manually. The data comes from the csv file.
Image 3 is another table I made not with the points for each question for each student, but with the number of grades all students have reached. This could be: 2 have grade 1, 5 have grade 2, etc. "Durchschnitt" is average.
The problem is not getting the data into a csv file (Excel), or getting this data into the document with datatool (image 3), but to get the data to the correct position in the document. All calculations (sum of points, percent, grade, etc.) are made in Excel. The "Erwartungshorizont" table is created by schule and the size depends on the number of questions in the exam. Here I have an example with three questions where one has two parts.
For the table I only need the data from "a, b, c and d".
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[fach=Physik,lerngruppe={7a},typ=kl,erwartungshorizontAnzeigen,module={Bewertung}]{schule}
\usepackage{datatool}

\title{Optik}
\author{Tom}
\date{16.12.2024}

\begin{document}

\begin{aufgabe}[points=3]
Task 1. \erwartung{Solution 1}{3}
\end{aufgabe}

\begin{aufgabe}[points=2]
Task 2 \erwartung{Solution 2}{2}
\end{aufgabe}

\begin{aufgabe}[points=14]
\begin{teilaufgaben}
\teilaufgabe Task 3, Part 1 \erwartung{Solution 3, Part 1}{5}
\teilaufgabe Task 3, Part 2 \erwartung{Solution 3, Part 2}{3}
\end{teilaufgaben}
\end{aufgabe}
\end{document}

The csv looks like this, a, b, c and d are the three tasks (with 30 rows for this class):
First name;Family name;a;b;c;d;Points Task 2;Points Task 3;percentage;grade number;grade name;quantity with grade 1;quantity with grade 2;quantity with grade 3;quantity with grade 4;quantity with grade 5;quantity with grade 6;average;date
First name;Family name;0;0;0;0;0;0,00;6;ungenügend;0;0;0;0;0;30;6,0;16.12.24

The datatool code:
\DTLsetseparator{;}
\DTLloaddb[noheader,keys={Vorname,Name,a,b,c,d,Punkte,Prozent,Note,Notenname,sehrgut,gut,befriedigend,ausreichend,mangelhaft,ungenuegend,Durchschnitt,Datum}]{noten}{Noten2.csv}

\begin{DTLenvforeach}{noten}
{\Vorname=Vorname,
\Name=Name,
\a=a,
\b=b,
\c=c,
\d=d,
\Punkte=Punkte,
\Prozent=Prozent,
\Note=Note,
\Notenname=Notenname,
\sehrgut=sehrgut,
\gut=gut,
\befriedigend=befriedigend,
\ausreichend=ausreichend,
\mangelhaft=mangelhaft,
\ungenuegend=ungenuegend,
\Durchschnitt=Durchschnitt,
\Datum=Datum}
\end{DTLenvforeach}

I get the first picture, I want the second but for each student in my csv. The third is an example of what I can do.
I get now: 30 pages of this type (picture three) after the exam but before the Erwartungshorizont in my document.
I want: 1 exam page, 30 Erwartungshorizont pages with individual name and points for each student in column 3 in one document.
I am also happy with: 30 exam pages with each individual name in the head and 30 Erwartungshorizont pages with points in column 3 in one document.
Of course I could make a table with the results on my own (without schule), but I am sure that it is possible of making the table with the points with schule. I just can't.




Because it seems, your question is independent from using scrartcl and would be the same using article, I've removed tag [tag:koma-script]. What I've not understand is the relation to [tag:datatool]. Can you at least show and example of your csv file or the csv file you are thinking about and also a sketch or (better) a manual made example of the table you expect.

Thanks for edit. article should go as well, but I'm used to koma in germany, also for letters. I hope it works better now.
I want to use datatool for a serial letter kind of document with points for each student in the "Erwartungshorizont"-table. The data is in the csv.

So this is data base related. Though you can use one big table (Excel temptation), it’s usually more efficient to formulate a problem in terms of relations amongst different smaller tables (Access or mysql approach). // Your problem sounds to me like there are two entities, the task (for all), and pupils with their individual achievements. The relationship amongst both is the task-ID. That’s harder to do in Excel and simple with Access. // The individual tables you want then are just queries. // Is this more or less your situation?

If you use Linux, take a look to auto-multiple-choice (AMC) that is far of you specific goal (make a table with datatool, etc.),  but can make invidivual exams with a single latex file and show indivual reports of the evaluation.

@MS-SPO From my point of view, it is more LaTeX-related. Making an Excel-file and making a csv and importing into LaTeX is no problem, I have made serial letters with that. My problem is the table which schulegenerates and the implementation of the points of each pupil for each task.

@Fran I'm working on a mac with TeXStudio.

Thank you. If it's "the same as before", what's different now? Please make that more visible in your question. Thank you

I use textmerg and Calc rather than datatool and Excel, but generally do all the calculations in the spreadsheet.
